# How to construct a Bitstring of variable length in C

Tags: c, arrays, bit

I want to write a function `rand_bit_string(int k, int n)` in C which generates a random bit string of length `n` containing exactly `k` ones.

My question is, how to design a data structure that represents the bit string of length `n`. The smallest data type in C is `char` which contains 8 bits. So I think about returning a `char` pointer which points to the first element of a `char` array. The array's size have to be the ceiling of `n/sizeof(char)`.

Comment: "So I think about returning a char pointer which points to the first element of a char array". Sounds like a good starting point and answers your own question. Please go ahead and try to code it and then come back if you have a more specific question to ask. BTW, `sizeof(char)` is 1.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(char)` is always 1, so dividing `n` by it will have no effect.

The size of allocation in `char`s can be computed as `(n+7)/8`. Adding `7` to `n` before performing integer division ensures that there is enough space in cases when `n` is not divisible by `8`.

As far as the return value goes, you could return `char*`, but then the caller would need to maintain the connection between `n` that they pass and the `char*` they got back. Alternatively, you could create a `struct` to keep the two together:

```
struct bit_sequence {
    char *bits;
    size_t n;
};
```

You could also add functions for accessing bits of `bit_sequence`, e.g.

```
int get_bit(bit_sequence *seq, size_t index) {
    if (index > seq->n) {
        // Report an error
    }
    size_t pos = index / 8;
    size_t bit = index % 8;
    return 1 & ((seq->bits[pos]) >> bit);
}
```